# Find all the valid week days from a given string separated by commas and dashes

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have UI editor from which user can select any number of days.
If the user selects continuous days, those are represented by dashes or hyphens, but if non-continuous days are selected then those are represented by commas..
`eg - String - M,W,F` - Non Continuous days.
`eg - String - M-F` - User selected continuous 5 days.

From backend point of view, if we are getting some string like `M-Tu,Th,Sa-Su` or `M-W,F-Su` etc combination, how to find the valid days from this ?.

I have created a constant array to either loop or check the value

```
DAYS: ['M', 'Tu', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'Sa', 'Su']
let userInput = 'M-Tu,Th,Sa-Su' or 'M-W,F-Su'

SomeMethod(userInput) {
  let validDays = [];
  const commaSeperatedDays = userInput?.split(',');
  const contDaysFromCommaSeparatedDays = commaSeperatedDays.map(x => 
  x.split('-'));
  let indDays = validDays.push(contDaysFromCommaSeparatedDays.map(x => 
  findIndividualDays(x)));

  //When only continuous days are there
  const ContinuousDays = days?.split('-');
}

function findIndividualDays(days) {
//getting confused here how to handle cases - if there is any inbuilt library ?
        if (days.length === 1) {
            return days[0];
        }
        let indDays = [];
        const startIndex = constants.DAYS.indexOf(days[0]);
        const endIndex = constants.DAYS.indexOf(days[1]);
        for (let index = startIndex; index <= endIndex; index++) {
            const element = constants.DAYS[index];
            indDays.push(element);
        }
        return { ...indDays };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add an option for fun, I like using generator functions

```js
const DAYS = ['M', 'Tu', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'Sa', 'Su'];

function* enumerateDays(inputString){
    for(const value of inputString.split(',')){
    const [start,end] = value.split('-');
    if(end)
        for(index = DAYS.indexOf(start), endIndex = DAYS.indexOf(end) ;index <= endIndex;index++)
            yield DAYS[index];
    else
        yield start;
  }
}



//test cases
const test = (inputString) => console.log(...enumerateDays(inputString));
test( 'M-Tu,Th,Sa-Su');
test('M-W,F-Su');
test('M-Su');
test('M,Tu,Th-Sa');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const DAYS = ['M', 'Tu', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'Sa', 'Su'];
const DAY_DELIMITER = ',';
const DAY_INTERVAL_DELIMITER = '-';

const inputSample1 = 'M-Tu,Th,Sa-Su';
const inputSample2 = 'M-W,F-Su';

const intervalToDays = (interval) => {
    if (interval.includes(DAY_INTERVAL_DELIMITER)) {
        // if it is an interval, break it down into days
        const [startDay, endDay] = interval.split(DAY_INTERVAL_DELIMITER);
        const continuousDays = [];
        for (i = DAYS.indexOf(startDay); i <= DAYS.indexOf(endDay); i++) {
            continuousDays.push(DAYS[i]);
        }
        return continuousDays.join(DAY_DELIMITER);
    } else {
        // if it is just one day, return it as is
        return interval;
    }
}

const parseDays = (inputString) => {
    const intervals = inputString.split(DAY_DELIMITER);
    return intervals.map(interval => intervalToDays(interval)).join(DAY_DELIMITER);
}

console.log(parseDays(inputSample1));
console.log(parseDays(inputSample2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified my solution little bit and this is working for me.

```js
const DAYS = ['M', 'Tu', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'Sa', 'Su'];
const inputSample1 = 'M-Tu,Th,Sa-Su';
const inputSample2 = 'M-W,F-Su';
const inputSample3 = 'M-F';
const inputSample4 = 'W,F-Su';

function findIndividualDays(days, validDays) {
   if (days.length === 1) {
      validDays.push(days[0]);
   }
   const startIndex = DAYS.indexOf(days[0]);
   const endIndex = DAYS.indexOf(days[1]);
   for (let index = startIndex; index <= endIndex; index++) {
      const element = DAYS[index];
      validDays.push(element);
   }
}

const parseDays = (inputString) => {
    let validDays = [];
    const commaSeperatedDays = inputString?.split(',');
    const contDaysFromCommaSeparatedDays = commaSeperatedDays.map(x => x.split('-'));
    contDaysFromCommaSeparatedDays.map(x => findIndividualDays(x, validDays));
    return validDays;
}

console.log(parseDays(inputSample1));
console.log(parseDays(inputSample2));
console.log(parseDays(inputSample3));
console.log(parseDays(inputSample4));
```